# in(3,7,1,5) need this order wise result

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `rsoft_module_fields` WHERE id in (3,7,1,5);
```

this is my query but the result show like id's orderwise, but I need the order as What I given in `in`  condition.

am expected result is given below
id 3 should be in 1 st row,
id 7 should be in 2 nd row,
id 1 should be in 3 rd row,
id 5 should be in 4 th row

and screenshot also attached for reference[image]

Comment: If you want to use this values list in ORDER BY then it must be not values list but rowset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM `rsoft_module_fields` t1
JOIN (SELECT 3 id, 1 sorting_order UNION  ALL
      SELECT 7, 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 1, 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5, 4) t2 USING (id)
ORDER BY t2.sorting_order
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `rsoft_module_fields` 
WHERE id in (3,7,1,5)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '3,7,1,5');
```